# Load Freebase full dump into OWLIM-SE

Tags: freebase, sesame

I have downloaded the full RDF Freebase dump file 'freebase-rdf-2012-12-09-00-00.gz'(7.5GB) from this link http://download.freebaseapps.com/

This data dump uses the the Turtle RDF syntax as defined here http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_dumps

How can I load data from this .gz file into OWLIM-SE (Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loading into OWLIM the 'getting-startted' application from the delivery could be used

```
     c:\owlim-se-5.3.5777\getting-started>example.cmd 
       url=http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame repository=myrepId
       preload=C:/baseKBLite queryfile=none
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the reply from [freebase-discuss] mailing list:

This Freebase dump should be unpacked, splitted and run thru fix scripts.
More details here

```
   http://people.apache.org/~andy/Freebase20121223
```